# write a file with a Turkish character

Tags: python

How can I print Turkish?

```
open("save.txt", "w+").write("C:\Müzikler")
folder = open("save.txt", "r+").read()
os.listdir(folder)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 
C:\xfczikler'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For special characters (or in your case, accents) you need to encode with utf-8.

Do this with:

```
open("save.txt", 'w+', encoding='utf-8').write("C:\Müzikler")
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: Sorry, I made an edit that might have fixed that. Can you try the new changes I made?

Comment: this is working. Thank you man.